# How to cast parent-child classes in java?

Tags: java, casting, parent-child

I am faced with an implementation question.
The question is whether it is possible to cast "grandfather" to "child" in java.

For example:

This is the parent class

```
  public class IDDocument {
    public IDDocument() {
    }
  }
```

This is the class that inherits from its parent called IDDocument

```
  public class Passport extends IDDocument {
    public Passport() {
    }
  }
```

And now, there is this class that inherits from Passport

```
  public class SLPassport extends Passport {
    public SLPassport() {
    }
  }
```

Knowing this, I want to know if it is possible to cast IDDocument to SLPassport.

This problem arose from the fact that the information that I receive from a service is contained in an IDDocument type, but I also need data that is only contained in SLPassport and it is necessary to use IDDocument.

Previously, I was able to cast Passport to IDDocument like this:

```
((Passport) idDocument).getSomeMethod();
```

So I retrieved data that only the child class contains.

Now as I said, my goal is to capture data but from the passport child class with IDDocument.

Comment: That would be easy enough to test with about a dozen lines of Java code.

Comment: Actually, I already know the answer.  Yes, it's possible, because runtime polymorphism exists.  Of course that pertains mostly to inheritance.

Comment: In practice, you're not necessarily going to know the parent type.  The whole point of using an interface is to comply with the interface, not to pass an interface type and then upcast it.

Comment: If the service returns `IdDocument`, then what makes you believe it's safe to assume it's an `SlPassport`? Why not return `SlPassport` directly?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class A, a class B that inherits from A, and a class C that inherits from B, class C also inherits from A. Here's [an explanation of polymorphism](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_polymorphism.asp) that's relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, assuming the instance is really an `SLPassport` instance. I'd also suggest you explicitly check this before casting in order to avoid `ClassCastException`s:

```java
if (idDocument instanceof SLPassport) {
    ((SLPassport) idDocument).doSomethingSpecific();
} else {
    System.err.println("Not an SLPassport"); // Or some better error handling
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An SLPassport **object** can be cast to:
IDDocument, Passport, Object or SLPassport

So if you did something like:

```
Passport myPass = new SLPassport();
SLPassport mySlPass = (SLPassport) myPass;
```

it would be valid.